# typescript variables type grouping

Tags: typescript

```
let isie:boolean = (/msie/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie
let isie6:boolean = (/msie 6/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie 6
let isie7:boolean = (/msie 7/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie 7
let isie8:boolean = (/msie 8/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie 8
let isie9:boolean = (/msie 9/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie 9
let isie10:boolean = (/msie 10/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //ie 9
let isfirefox:boolean = (/firefox/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //firefox
let isapple:boolean = (/applewebkit/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //safari,chrome
let isopera:boolean = (/opera/i).test(navigator.userAgent); //opera
let isios:boolean = (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i).test(navigator.userAgent);//ios
let isipad:boolean = (/(ipad)/i).test(navigator.userAgent);//ipad
let isandroid:boolean = (/android/i).test(navigator.userAgent);//android
```

i'm using typescript,

Can you group types for many variables at once?

For example,

```
[isie,isie6,isie7,isie = boolean]
```

Comment: please explain, or give a pseudo code for example

Comment: how about storing this data in an object instead of a bunch of separate variables ?